# How to check the Android source version?

Tags: android, android-source

How to check the Android source version ? I had referred this [link](http://goo.gl/2sja0) but it does not seem to be very proper way of checking the version. Like in linux kernel we can open the main Makefile to see the kernel version, similarly is there any way to find the version of Android ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"  
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
```

Comment: There are many AndroidManifest.xml. Do we have to refer any specific AndroidManifest.xml or any we can refer ?

Comment: you have to refer only specific project's AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

use `/proc/version`

```
private String getInfo() {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        sb.append("abi: ").append(Build.CPU_ABI).append("\n");
        String abi=Build.CPU_ABI;
        Toast.makeText(CpuinfoActivity.this, "CPU ABI is :::"+abi, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if (new File("/proc/cpuinfo").exists()) {
            try {
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("/proc/version")));
                String aLine;
                while ((aLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(aLine + "\n");
                }
                if (br != null) {
                    br.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Hope this helps.